# Promise not resolved correctly when routing

Tags: angularjs

So basically I am using resolve in $routeProvider in order to get my current user's information before I instantiate the controller. 
This is how I do it:

```
userMan.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/userManagement', {
        templateUrl: 'userManagement/userManagement.html',
        controller: 'userManCtrl',
        resolve: {
            myUser:function($http){
                console.log("I am about to make the call");
                $http.get("/irods-cloud-backend/searchByMetadata/getCurrentUser").then( function( result ) {
                    console.log(result.data);
                    return result.data;
                },
                function( result ) {
                    alert("Unable to find any users! Please try again...");
                })
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

My controller also looks something like this:

```
userMan.controller('userManCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$location', 'myUser',
function($scope, $log, $http, $location, myUser){

    var currUser = myUser;
```

Basically my error is that currUser is undefined. This prevents me to check the user's permissions and such. 
I have also used:

```
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(event, current){
        alert("loaded!!");
    });
```

To see when this promise is resolved, but I see the alert message as soon as I load into the tab. 
I then tried to use a dummy return object simply like

```
return { someAttr: 'val'};
```

This functions just fine.. I know its not a promise but did that for sanity purposes..

Any clues for the error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't return from the myUser method, so there's nothing to wait for but `undefined`. As @JoelCDoyle commented:

> Your resolve method must return a promise. $http method returns a promise.

```
resolve: {
        myUser:function($http){
            // return here!
            return $http.get("/irods-cloud-backend/searchByMetadata/getCurrentUser").then( function( result ) {
                console.log(result.data);
                return result.data;
            }
```

Comment: Sorry could you expand on that please? If I remove the return statement how am I supposed to access it?     var currUser = myUser would work?

Comment: Your resolve method must return a promise. `$http` method returns a promise.

Comment: Hi I am still unsure of how can I use the promise returned by $http, the whole point is to get the current user. I was assuming currUser = myUser would allow me to use the object returned by the $http call. However myUser is undefined..

Answer (score 0):

After feedback from @JoelCDoyle and @baao, I used a different approach.
I simply created a service that handled the GET request and used that in my resolve. 
More on this can be viewed [here](https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved/)